# Recommendation for LONGTEXT empty value: '' or NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field called `synopsis` -- sometimes this will be provided and sometimes it won't. Is there any difference in storing the default value as an empty string with the field being `NOT NULL` vs. storing the value as `NULL`?

The two comparative fields would be:

```
- `synopsis` longtext NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
- `synopsis` longtext NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

What is recommended here? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to store something (empty string) if there is no value? Better use `null` which indicates exactly that - no value.

Use the `not null` condition for columns that need to have a value by definition. For instance an employee needs to have a social security number but does not need to have a middle name.